# Endpoint in Microsoft Graph Explorer to retrieve a list of all applications a user has access to

Tags: oauth, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, microsoft365

I'm working on a project where I need to retrieve a list of all applications that a user has access to in Microsoft Graph Explorer. By "applications," I mean Microsoft 365 applications like Outlook, PowerPoint, Word, and others.

I've been exploring the Microsoft Graph API, but I couldn't find a direct endpoint that provides this information. I am specifically using Microsoft Graph Explorer for testing and development purposes.

Is there a specific endpoint in Microsoft Graph Explorer or a combination of endpoints that I can use to achieve this? I need to get a list of applications that a user has access to, similar to what is shown on the "My Apps" page on myapps.com.

If anyone has experience with Microsoft Graph API or Microsoft Graph Explorer and can guide me on how to approach this, I would greatly appreciate it. Any example code or API calls would be helpful.

I expected the response from the /me/applications endpoint to include a list of individual applications that the user has access to, such as Outlook, PowerPoint, Sharepoint, admin, contacts, Word, and any other Microsoft 365 applications assigned to the user.

Comment: The Graph API doesn't have any endpoint for MyApps. There is blog series where some guy tried to read data from MyApps (hack): https://svrooij.io/2023/06/12/teams-hacktogether-getting-access/

Comment: Hello Brian Tompsett,

I tried the solution that you gave me, but unfortunately, it didn't work, and I couldn't find a solution in the end. I'm still in need of this part for my project. If you have another solution, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no Graph endpoint for MyApps. However, if looking to retrieve M365 applications, you can use [licenseDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-licensedetails?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) ([https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id/upn}/licenseDetails](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bid/upn%7D/licenseDetails)) as a work around but you would need to refer to the Service Plan identifiers for mapping as listed here- [Product names and service plan identifiers for licensing - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/licensing-service-plan-reference)

Comment: Please, I would like to add another question because I also want to retrieve the application names and their links to create a SharePoint web part that includes these applications, similar to myapps.microsoft.com.